# Moving localhost to new directory: 403 Error with permissions set

Tags: 18.04, permissions, apache2, dropbox, localhost

I had my apache localhost set up and working in /home/x/Documents/Sites, but I wanted to move the Sites folder into my Dropbox folder in order to keep it backed up.

I moved the Sites folder from /home/x/Documents to /home/x/Dropbox.

I changed the path in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf and used a2ensite to update. This is now the 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/x/Dropbox/Sites

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The moved /Sites folder retained its access privileges, and I have also reset them to check:

```
drwxr-sr-x 38 x www-data      4096 Mar  7 18:59  Sites
```

However, I am still getting a 403 Forbidden error on all localsite queries. I don't know what else to do. All help gratefully receved.

Comment: Are you sure it will run from the Dropbox directory?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/home/x/Dropbox/`?

Comment: @David I'm not, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't, as it's just another directory, as I understand it.

Comment: @MartinThornton `drwxr-xr-x  43 x www-data     4096 Apr 16 15:28  Dropbox`

Answer (score 0):

Add this config in this virtual-host

```
<Directory "/home/x/Dropbox/Sites">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

so final config will be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/x/Dropbox/Sites

    <Directory "/home/x/Dropbox/Sites">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```